# Перевод markdown редактора

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Здравствуйте.
При нажатии на кнопку в редакторе, чтобы вставить список, как нумерованный так и  маркированный, в текстовое поле вставляется текст по умолчанию:
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

В слове "списка" лишняя буква О.

P.S. Почему-то предыдущий текст "не отвечает стандартам качества". Какой-то уж очень суровый фильтр "минимального качества". Этот текст написан в попытке обойти его. Заранее прощу прощения.

Comment: Насчёт минимального качества, это автоматический фильтр. Ему, как и всем эвристикам, свойственно ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

Теперь всё работает, грамматических ошибок нет:

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

*текст курсивом*

введите сюда описание ссылки

> Цитата

```
введите сюда код
```

1. Элемент списка

   - Элемент списка

### Заголовок